# Sending data from Flash to PHP using POST method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a developed a application that allows users to draw simple images on a canvas. The name of the movieclip(canvas) is canvas_mc.

I need to save this drawing on the server using php. I have to convert the movieclip (canvas_mc) into  png and jpeg and save it. I have successfully save it on local drive using some classes available in

http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/smoothdraw/index.html

How can I save it on server using PHP. I have been asked to use the post method. If possible give me the code also as I just moved into programming from design :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how to convert your image into data and such, but here's a class I have lying around that you can use to transfer data to a PHP script (which can from there insert the data into a database).

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * @author Marty Wallace
     * @version 1.00
     */
    public class PHPData extends Object
    {
        /**
         * Sends data to a PHP script
         * @param script A URL to the PHP script
         */
        public function send(script:String, vars:URLVariables):void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(script);

            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(req);

            // listeners
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }

        /**
         * Called when a response has been received from a PHP script
         * @param e Event.COMPLETE
         */
        private function _complete(e:Event):void
        {
            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

            var i:String;
            for(i in vars)
            {
                trace(i + ": " + vars[i]);
            }

            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var php:PHPData = new PHPData();
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

vars.imagedata = your_image_data;

php.send("your_php_script.php", vars);
```

Comment: I understand after some searching that I can convert my MovieClip into ByteArray and send it. I found the code for conversion                 var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
buffer.writeObject(MOVIE_CLIP_HERE);
buffer.position = 0;
buffer.writeBytes(...);       I found it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482053/as3-export-a-movieclip-or-canves-to-swf  But what should be argument of writeBytes function. The documentation says it 'The ByteArray object'. But I just created it I understand.I think then using the class and putting vars.imagedata = buffer;   the job will be done.

Comment: Cool, if that's the case then you should be able to send that over to PHP using the above.

Comment: What I cant figure out is what should be the 1st argument of the writeBytes function in                                                 var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
buffer.writeObject(MOVIE_CLIP_HERE);
buffer.position = 0;
buffer.writeBytes(...);

Comment: Not sure, never used a ByteArray before. Check Adobes livedocs (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) to have a good look at arguments for methods and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much Marty. You were so helpful.

Comment: Hi Marty , I understand you are into Game development and stuff like that which involves a lot of Math and Physics. I remember one post of yours regarding flight of path of a projectile. I am also interested in Game development but my current work is application development and not Game development. However if you have any queries regarding Math and Physics in Game development I would be more than happy to help.  That is an area of expertise of mine.