# Converting a MovieClip to ByteArray

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have to convert a MovieClip to ByteArray and send it to php using the POST method. The person handling php says that only ByteArray  needs to be send and conversion to JPG and PNG can be done from PHP side. When I built the option for saving on the local machine the following steps were used.

1. Converting to Bitmapdata
2. Using JPGEncoder and PNGEncoder on the  Bitmapdata
3. Then assiging to byte array variable.

So in this case different byte arrays were used for saving in case of JPG and PNG and it worked.

I found the code to convert movieclip to bytearray in Stackoverflow itself

[AS3: Export a MovieClip or Canvas to swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482053/as3-export-a-movieclip-or-canves-to-swf)

```
var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
buffer.writeObject(MOVIE_CLIP_HERE);
buffer.position = 0;
buffer.writeBytes(...);
```

What should be the parameter of  writeBytes function of buffer object. Assume that the name of the movieclip is canvas_mc.

I have figured out the php part already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `writeObject(MovieClip)` will serialize your clip using AMF, which will be harder for PHP to deal with if the server wants an image capture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use `ByteArray.writeObject()` and parse a `MovieClip`..

You need to use `bitmapData.getPixels()` which returns a `ByteArray` representing the pixels of your bitmap.

Here's a quick example:

```
const WIDTH:uint = 100;
const HEIGHT:uint = 100;

var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

// create BitmapData
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(WIDTH,HEIGHT,true,0);
bmd.draw(YOUR_MOVIE_CLIP);

// your byte array
var ba:ByteArray = bmd.getPixels(rect);
trace(ba.length);
```

Basically what you want to do is use `BitmapData.draw()` to get your MovieClip graphics and store them as a ByteArray.

Comment: +1 for getPixels(), but I find the example confusing since it spends so much time in "draw square".  Not incorrect, just not relevant to the problem (and why not fillRect, anyway?).

Comment: True, I'll simplify the example. And actually I have no idea it somehow escaped my mind :s