# How to create a new swf on the server from a moviclip in current swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime, export

I have a movieClip on the stage with a loaded swf playing animation and sound. I want to export the movieclip to swf. I thought I would be able to do something similar to the jpeg export?. 
The main swf and the one being loaded in to be copied are on the same server.

I've searched about but I have not come across anything that outlines what needs to be done.
Any chance of a bit more in-depth explanation as to how to accomplish this?

I did have one post on here already about where someone had a similar question but the moders felt a need to delete it :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [Ming](http://www.libming.org/) which might suit your needs.

Also, as serverside swf generation is not trivial, do you really need it? If you need a dynamic swf, you could also create a template and create the content using flashvars in combination with a serverside language like PHP.

Comment: Hi there. What I have is a video animation(SWF) that has an image loaded into a key points. This works fine and does what it needs to. I pass an id to the player and it loads in the image that linked to that id. Now I've been asked if I can as well as the above have an option that will create a unique swf that also has that image already embedded in it. This is so that user can take the swf and upload it to something like youtube. I would have thought given similar can be done but export to image instead that export to swf should not be that difficult?

Comment: Here's another tool which might come in handy http://code.google.com/p/swfreplacer/wiki/Intro

Comment: Sorry that's no good either since it does not export actionscript 3. I did come across this post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482053/as3-export-a-movieclip-or-canves-to-swf?answertab=oldest#tab-top[/link] but it lacks detailed explanation.